# Linear transformation via taking derivatives, what are the matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider the real-vector space of polynomials (i.e. real coefficients) $f(x)$ of at most degree $3$, let's call that space $X$. And consider the real-vector space of polynomials (i.e. real coefficients) of at most degree $2$, call that $Y$. And consider the linear transformation $A$ from $X$ to $Y$ defined by the following:$$A(f) = 2f' - (x+1)f''.$$**Question 1.** What's the matrix of $A$ with regards to the bases $\mathfrak{X} = (1,x,x^2,x^3)$ of $X$ and $\mathfrak{Y} = (1, x, x^2)$ of $Y$?

**Question 2.** What's the matrix of $A$ with regards to the bases  $\mathfrak{X} = (1,x+1,(x+1)^2,(x+1)^3)$ of $X$ and $\mathfrak{Y} = (1, x+1, (x+1)^2)$ of $Y$?

I am looking for these two examples I thought of done in detail, given that the examples in my lecture notes are solely with concrete linear algebra things in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and are not in another setting. Seeing them done in detail would give me greater insight on how to move beyond the matrix setting. Thank you!

Comment: If $d_i$ is a basis for the domain and $r_j$ is a basis for the range, express $A(d_i)$ as a linear combination of the $d_j$. The coefficients will give you the $i$th column.

Comment: @copper.hat A(d$_i$) is an element in the codomain. Thus it is a linear combination of the r$_j$, What you have written is incorrect.

Comment: @JoelPereira: You are incorrect in your assertion that I am incorrect. $A(d_i)$ is a polynomial in $Y$. To obtain the matrix with respect to the basis $r_j$ you meed to write $A(d_i) = \sum_k \alpha_k r_k$. Then the coefficients $\alpha_k$ will be the $i$th column of the matrix. If you still think this is incorrect, please elaborate.

Comment: @copper.hat Correct...so A(d$_i$) is a linear combination of.....the r$_j$, not the d$_i$.

Comment: @JoelPereira: I stand corrected. Twice.

Comment: My first comment should read "...as a linear combination of the $r_j$". And my statement about an incorrect assertion is incorrect .

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For question $1$ assume $f(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ then

$$A(f)=2f' - (x+1)f''=2(b+2cx+3dx^2)-(x+1)(2c+6dx)=$$$$=2b+4cx+6dx^2-2cx-6dx^2-2c-6dx=(2b-2c)+(2c-6d)x$$

therefore

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&2&-2&0\\0&0&2&-6\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

For question $2$ we can proceed in the same way or to perform a change of basis.

Comment: @copper.hat There is also a mistake I'm fixing!

Comment: @copper.hat For Q2 are you suggesting to find the matrix by the same method?

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry I just realized that I've written "change of variables" instead of "change of basis" which I was thonking about. And also of course we don't need to do that, we can also proceed in that way.

Answer (score 0):

For a linear transformation, the entire mapping is dependent on the basis elements. Compute A(1), A(x), A(x$^2$), A(x$^3$). The image polynomials will form the columns of A.

Do the same with the second set of bases.

Comment: That is not correct. You need to express $A(x^k)$ in terms of the range basis.

Comment: The polynomials do not form the columns of $A$.